# Writing to database located on sdcard in phonegap is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am working on phonegap application, here is my condition,

I have a sqlite database which is saved on sdcard, I want to access it through phonegap.

I am able to access it using following code

var db = window.openDatabase("../../../../mnt/sdcard/test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);

but same code is not working for some devices. Above code is working on emulator, samsung tab2. But when I deployed application on mobile phone it is not working.

Following is my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="Test" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Comment: I suspect it could be the android permission issue. Post your `.manifest` file code.

Comment: Did you check permissions on `.manifest` ? . @AmolChakane may be right on this !

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission in your manifest file.

Refer [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Hope that helps.